# MS Access Dense Rank

Tags: sql, ms-access, rank, dense-rank

So I am trying to find a way to replicate the denserank() function on my MS Access table. I found the following query that has helped quite a bit:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.ColA
  ,( SELECT Count(*) 
     FROM
       Table1 AS T 
     WHERE
       T.ColA = Table1.ColA AND
       T.PrimaryKeyFieldName <= Table1.PrimaryKeyFieldName) AS ColB;
```

This query works great as a way of replicating the `rank()` function. However, I would like to modify this query so that it replicates `denserank()` instead. In other words, the ranking for groups now looks like this:

### Rank

0
0
0
3
3
3
6
6
6

Instead, what I am looking for is this:

### Rank

0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2

Another example of what I'm trying to achieve can be seen in Example #3 here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208946

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just want the RANK to increment starting from zero, and incrementing by 1 for each group?  If so, try this:

```
select T1.*,
   (select count(*)
    from (select distinct T2.flda
          from table1 as T2
         )  as T2
    where T2.flda <= T1.flda
   ) as dense_rank
From table1 as T1;
```

Here is a second query as I mentioned earlier. However, I don't know if this will give you the grouping that you want.

```
SELECT T1.*, 
   (select count(*)
    from (select distinct T2.flda, T2.fldb, T2.MyDate
          from table1 as T2
         )  as T2
    where (T2.flda <= T1.flda) AND (T2.MyDate <> T1.MyDate)
) AS dense_rank
FROM table1 AS T1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I thought the solution might involve another subquery, but wasn't sure.  

What exactly is "flda"? Never seen that before.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I probably should've mentioned, I have 2 more conditions in the WHERE clause that are used to signal a new group. One of these conditions is based on a groupID and the other is based on paymentDate. So the where clause would look something like this in your query:  
  
WHERE  

T2.groupID = T1.groupID AND  
T2.UID <= T1.UID AND  
T2.paymentDate <> T1.paymentDate  
  
Doing so results in an error that says:  
  
"The specified field 'T2.groupID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement."

Comment: First, "flda" is a seldom used, but effective way to refer to some unknown column located in the referenced table... in other words, it's just some field/column in your database... :) As for the additional WHERE error, you could change "(select distinct T2.flda" to "(select distinct T2.flda, T2.UID,  T2. MyDate" etc., but I believe you may not get the results you were looking for re RANK. Try it and see...

Comment: When I run the query as suggested, I still get the following error:

"The specified field 'T2.[GROUP_ID]' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of our SQL statement."

Comment: I updated my answer with another sample that uses more fields -- but may not work as you want. If you still get an error, please post your SQL and the fields in each table.